# Spring Vault Kubernetes Auth not accepting custom mount path

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-webclient, spring-vault

Using Spring Vault 2.1.2 and I cannot upgrade.  I am configuring an AbstractReactiveVaultConfiguration to use KubernetesAuthentication.

```
@Configuration
public class VaultConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveVaultConfiguration {

    @Value("${my.vault.endpoint.url}")
    private URI vaultEndpointURL;

    @Override
    public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
        return VaultEndpoint.from(vaultEndpointURL);
    }

    @Override
    public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {
        KubernetesAuthenticationOptions options = KubernetesAuthenticationOptions.builder()
                .role("myRole").path("foo/bar").build();

        return new KubernetesAuthentication(options, restOperations());
    }

}
```

This is producing:

```
org.springframework.vault.authentication.VaultLoginException: Cannot retrieve VaultToken from authentication chain; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
```

With sufficient logging, I have discovered that it is attempting to post to:

`POST /v1/auth/foo%2Fbar/login`

What is escaping the configured path of "foo/bar" and how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem with latest release [2.2.1.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/releases/tag/2.2.1.RELEASE). of spring-vault.

It has been fixed now. Yet to release the new version.

Refer the bug and fix [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/commit/ac38b83b4ced5d6972e8b3f376cc7376f2d7a579#diff-657c8ec834e3e13efeba6ae342d6016bL85-R85)

Reason for the bug:

Previously, we were **sending two arguments** to login method. `.login("auth/{mount}/login", options.getPath());`. Inside login method, this arguments will be given to HttpRequestBuilder.post(uriTemplate, uriVariables) which was converting the `/` to `%2F`

Currently, we are sending one one argument `AuthenticationUtil.getLoginPath(options.getPath())` this **will not** convert the `/` to `%2F`.

We can raise this issue to spring-vault and ask them to release the next version.